# How to reload namespace into repl after error?

Tags: clojure

During development, I often `require` a namespace and then discover that the source file has an error that prevents it from being compiled:

```
(require '[foo.bar :as fb])
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: ...
```

After I fix the error, I try to `require` the namespace again, but I can't:

```
(require '[foo.bar :as fb])
CompilerException java.lang.Exception: namespace 'foo.bar' not found, compiling: ...
```

My solution has been to kill the repl and run `lein repl` again, but that's obviously not ideal.

Is there a way to clean up the effects of the previous failed `require`?

(And why is the error "namespace ... not found"?  That doesn't make sense to me.  The source file is still there, and Clojure was able to find it a minute earlier--that's how I knew about the error.)

Comment: The namespace isn't found because it didn't successfully load. The namespace isn't automatically reloaded because `require` already made a note that the namespace had been required. This has to do with the logic of recursively evaluating the requires that a namespace requires, where many namespaces will require the same namespace... so it is useful to mark things off as already required while building the tree of namespaces to load.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, @noisesmith, along with the answer that provided just what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`require` takes an optional `:reload` argument that forces reloading of changes, even if `require` has already been run.

```
(require '[foo.bar :as foo] :reload)
```

This is useful when there was an error upon the initial loading of the namespace, or if you just want to load a newer version of the namespace.

There is also `:reload-all` for loading all the recursive required code of that namespace as well.